# IIS6 freezes when running ASP.NET MVC site on Windows Server 2003

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have an ASP.NET MVC website deployed on IIS6 running on Windows Service 2003.  Every day around 12:30 (and occasionally at other times), the w3wp.exe process goes up to 99% CPU, won't serve any pages, and will continue to remain stuck until I do an IISRESET.

I work at a small place, and I admit that it's not the optimal server setup (the server is also the domain controller and runs Microsoft Exchange).  You can berate me if you want.  I'm trying to get a VM to run my site in.  This is not what this question is about.

I'm just wondering if anyone else has experienced this kind of freezing with IIS6 and ASP.NET MVC.  I'm fully aware that it might be caused by my server setup, but I'm just trying to cover all of the bases before we make changes that we might not need.

I got a dump of the stack trace and used WinDbg to see what was on the stack, but it was all unmanaged code on every thread.  I'm pretty sure I know what I'm doing with WinDbg (although I'm not the uber-expert, so I guess I could be doing something wrong).

Comment: No, that was the first place I looked.

Comment: Have used IIS6+ws2003+Asp.net-Mvc without such a problems. You might want to try serverfault too. :)

Comment: have you managed to fix this issue? We have a very similar server setup and our site does exactly the same thing. It crashes even more often. I would really appreciate your answer because we have already lost many many hours trying to solve this and our client is going nuts about it.
Thanks a lot,
Jiri